# Python library to generate flash files

Tags: python, flash

I was wondering if there is any Python library out there which would allow me to generate  Flash files (a simple slide show of a bunch of images).

I tried installing [Ming](https://github.com/libming/libming) but was running into some problems, so was wondering if there is any other library out there with better documentation.

Comment: just wanted to suggest http://pyswftools.sourceforge.net/index.html, but it is based on libming :)

Comment: This looks really interesting, I'm just not able to install Ming :S The instructions seem really outdated, and I'm new to this, so am having a hard time figuring out how to get it going. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can do a workaround unless you find a python library for it.

You can use Flex SDK and the command line compiler (found in `/bin`).

Basically, setup the flash actionscript code with python, then compile it to an swf.

If you have images in a folder, then

```
[Embed(source="IMAGE-NAME")]
var Image:Class;

var image:* = new Image();
addChild(image);
```

embeds an image and adds it to the stage.

So, if you have more images, put it in a loop in python, when writing the actionscript file, like:

```
[Embed(source="IMAGE-NAME-1")]
var Image1:Class;

[Embed(source="IMAGE-NAME-2")]
var Image2:Class;

var image1:* = new Image1();
addChild(image1);

var image2:* = new Image2();
addChild(image2);
```

etc.

Hope this gives some idea. After this, you can write a timer or an interval for showing the actual image.

Something like

```
var totalFrames:int = ...;
var actualFrame:int = 0;
var lastImage:* = null;

flash.utils.setInterval(nextframe, 1000/30);

function nextframe():void
{
     //hide last visible image
     if(lastImage != null) lastImage.visible = false;

     //show next image
     lastImage = this["image" + actualFrame];
     lastImage.visible = true;

     actualFrame = (actualFrame + 1) % totalFrames;
}
```

Hide all images when adding to the stage (`image#.visible = false;`).

And so, with python you generate the actionscript, then run the command line compiler.

Hope this gives some idea.